# Do specific code depending on the WCF service behavior

Tags: wcf, web-config, servicebehavior

Is it a good idea to get the current WCF behavior withing a WCF operation contract and do some stuff depending on the current behavior?
If no: Why not?
If yes: How can I do that?

For example something like this:

```
// Interface
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataService
    {
         [OperationContract]
         DataResponse GetData(DataRequest request);
    }

// Implementation of the IDataService.GetData
public DataResponse GetData(DataRequest request)
{
    // get current behavior
    IBehavior currBevhavior = ...?

    if (currBehavior.name = ""){
        // custom code for this behavior
    }

    ...
}
```

Edit: The same thing for the binding: Is it a good idea to do stuff in code depending on which binding the current request came in? How can I do that?